# How do you define a Makefile-style variable in a solution to be used in multiple projects (VS 2008)?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, projects-and-solutions

I am working in a Visual Studio 2008 solution with multiple C# projects and some C++ projects and want to use post-build events to execute some 3rd party vendor command line tools.  These post-build events are needed in several projects.

I can hard code the path names and other files needed on the command line, but I really would prefer something more flexible.  Perhaps:

$(ToolsDir)\$(PackageBuilder) $(ThirdPartyDllFolder) $(SharedOutputFolder)

When I developed for UNIX and used makefiles to perform builds, I was able to define a variable in a high level makefile and have it inherited by children makefiles.  In this way, I could have all output go to a particular place, or look in a particular place for a library, etc.

Is there an equivalent thing that can be done using Visual Studio solutions, such that I could define something like an environment variable and then reference it in a project level post-build event?

EDIT: I am using Windows environment variables right now, but would prefer something that did not require setup outside of just downloading the code and building it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered environment variables in Windows?  I know it's not exactly the same thing, but you could set them with a batch file and execute that batch file post-build.

Comment: Scott, yes I actually use this method, but am searching for a method where a developer could just download the source code to a clean machine and build it without having to do extra "stuff".

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a while back.  My first "solution" was to create a tool that was built and run when a developer got the first "get" from the repository.  It was not pretty and was one additional step - but only once.

I abandoned that and now we have another method.  We put third-part tools in an svn repository (a different one than our source) and require a specific hierarchy and name for where that repository lives in relation to the root of our code base.  This way we can use relative paths with confidence in our post-build steps or other parts.

I agree that this is a bit of a weakness in the MS build tools.